# click button at end of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a stripe checkout button to pop up when someone clicks "create account" and then once they put in their credit card info the popup closes.

how would i get the "create account" button to be clicked programmatically after the popup closes?

Here's the sequence
1) user clicks create account button
2) popup opens 
3) popup closes and then button is clicked programmatically

I assume it's something like this but I haven't gotten it working yet. Button ID is #create_stripe

```
$("#create_stripe").click();
```

Code:

```
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test',
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  $('#create_stripe').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();

  });


</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('create_stripe').click();

Comment: @charlietfl sorry not trying to click on the iFrame. trying to click on my button which is #stripe_create after the popup closes.

Comment: what is purpose of the click after it closes? I doubt that you will get access to the popup close event

Comment: @charlietfl to create the account in my rails app. but i don't want the user to click twice. basically, user puts in their info, clicks create account once, stripe popup opens, they put in their credit info, clicks submit, popup closes, and then right now they would have to click create account again. i just want it to auto click that since they already clicked it once.

Comment: but the acceptance in popup should submit a form to your server. This all sounds like an XY Problem

Comment: @charlietfl the popup is for stripe. it only deals with stripe as far as i know. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: you need to use the `token` callback to submit your form or ajax. All this click issue is definitely an XY-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger it.  Since you want to execute the code you've placed inside of a `click` event, you can trigger it with `$("#create_stripe").trigger('click')`

Edit: in light of your comments below, I think you need something like this:

```
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test',
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    },
    closed: function (){
        $("#create_stripe").trigger('click')
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks. so this works but the order is not exactly right. how would i have this happen after the popup closes?

Comment: @rs19 That depends on the popup.  Usually the popup plugin provides an event you can attach to that will run javascript right after the popup is hidden.

Comment: @rs19 looks like your looking for the `closed` option from https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom-callback-closed.  That callback should run after the dialog is gone.  There you can call the trigger.

Comment: thanks. does this seem right?  `$(window).on('closed', function() {
   $("#create_stripe").click()
});`

Comment: That's attaching the click event to the window `closed` event.  I don't think that's quite what you're looking for.  I'm not even sure if my solution is correct, but try the code in my edit and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$("#create_stripe").click()`. See [click() in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/). Use it directly however :`

```
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
   $("#create_stripe").click()
});
```

Comment: thanks. so this works but the order is not exactly right. how would i have this happen after the popup closes?

Comment: You should use a conditional test to see if the window is in the desired state (closed popup). If you only want to delay the call for UI reasons, you should use ```setTimeout(function(){$("#create_stripe").click()}, <time>)```. This depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these:

```
document.getElementById('create_stripe').click(); 
$('#create_stripe').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `trigger()` method. `click()` method is ambiguous because it works as a listener and as a trigger. So if you call trigger you don't have ambiguous behaviours:

```
 $(element).trigger('click'); // or the event you need
```

More info:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: nothing ambiguous about it ... if no arguments provided it does exactly the same thing as `trigger()`

Comment: That's an ambiguity. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

use  `$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );`